# Instantiating multiple mutable variable

Tags: java, variables, instantiation, mutable

I have instantiated multiple mutable variable:

```
SimpleStringBuffer a=new SimpleStringBuffer();
SimpleStringBuffer b=new SimpleStringBuffer();
```

I have done this 11 times, I know there is some way to avoid doing it using array or collections but I am not sure how. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You should add a tag for the language you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array of `SimpleStringBuffer`s:

```
SimpleStringBuffer arr = new SimpleStringBuffer[11];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    arr[i] = new SimpleStringBuffer();
}
```

Or a `List`:

```
List<SimpleStringBuffer> list = new ArrayList<>(11);
for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
    list.add(new SimpleStringBuffer());
}
```

Comment: What should be done if I  want to repeat the same procedure for the Map ?

Comment: @user4230977 What Map? Can you elaborate the question please?

Comment: If i instantiate map in multiple places like this                                                    
     Map row1=new HashMap();
     Map row2=new HashMap();
     Map row3=new HashMap();
     Map row4=new HashMap();                                                                                      Is there a similar way to avoid multiple instantiation?

Comment: @user4230977 the same technique will work for that too